# Where should this SFMC provided script be placed to secure my SmartCapture CloudPages?

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage, smart-capture

I'm hoping to secure my CloudPages Smart Capture forms using the script provided by SFMC on [this page](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_cp_cloud_pages_security_best_practices.htm&type=5).

I've pasted the script in various pages on the code view screen and no matter where I place it, the formatting of my form is removed.

This is how the form looks prior to adding the script.

[image]

This is how the form looks after adding the script.

[image]

Below is the codeview. Where should the script be placed?

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
 <style class="main_style">
.layout-canvas-g { background-color: #FFFFFF; border: none; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0px; width: 100%; }
.flex-container { justify-content: flex-start !important; display: flex !important; flex-wrap: wrap !important; }
.flex-container div { margin: 0px 2px; }
.layout-canvas-g > .header, .layout-canvas-g > .section, .layout-canvas-g > .footer { position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; overflow-wrap: break-word; }
.layout-canvas-g > .section { margin: 10px 0px; }
.layout-canvas-g > .section > .columns { box-sizing: border-box; overflow-wrap: break-word; }
body { color: #000000; font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px; margin: 0px auto; max-width: 100%; background-color: transparent; line-height: 1; padding: 0px; }
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .mobile-hidden { display: none !important; }
  .responsive-td { width: 100% !important; display: block !important; padding: 0px !important; }
}
.layout-canvas-g > .section > .columns { width: 100%; }
</style>

</head>
  
<body>
  
<div class="layout layout-canvas-g">
 <div class="section">
  <div class="columns col1">
   <div data-type="slot" data-key="col1"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: just put the response headers at the very top of the page. Make sure that you also include the "<script runat="server">" part. and i am not sure.. but maybe the line right after that tag should be Platform.Load("Core", "1");

Comment: I've posted it at the very top, but it still changes the formatting.